# Printing values from an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file which should have 100 lines. Each line is identified by an id (001,002,003 etc.). But sometimes some lines miss. E.g: Some text files might only have 93 lines. I am checking for the missing lines.

This is my code for it.

```
bool[] idCheck = new bool[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   idCheck[i] = false;
   for (int j = 0; j < FileIdArray.Length; j++) //FileIdArray is the list of all my Ids.
   {
        if (i == Convert.ToInt32(FileIdArray[j]))
        {
          idCheck[i] = true;
        }
   }
}
ResultBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("*****************************************"));
for (int i = 0; i < idCheck.Length; i++)
{
   idCheck[0] = true;          
   if (idCheck[i] == false)
   {
      ResultBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Missing Id's from File 1 are {0}", i));
   }                                    
}
```

My o/p for this Looks like this:

```
*****************************************
Missing Id's from File 1 are 26
Missing Id's from File 1 are 41
Missing Id's from File 1 are 56
Missing Id's from File 1 are 88
Missing Id's from File 1 are 94
Missing Id's from File 1 are 98
Missing Id's from File 1 are 99
```

I like my o/p to look like this:

```
Missing Id's from File 1 are 26,41,56,88,94,98,99.
```

I realize I placed my `ResultBuilder` inside the loop and hence I have the repetition. But when I tried saving `i` to a string I was getting an exception.

Comment: What kind of exception did you get?

Comment: Please provide the exact exception you are getting.

Comment: This is a part of a big program i am writing. I send in 3 arguments for my program(3 text files).  The exception is that the app is not picking up the first file.First file is the file for which i am doing this.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException:  Input String was not in a correct format. and i get my line numbers where the function starts and ends

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your bottom loop with:

```
var missing = idCheck.Select((b, idx) => new { IsPresent = b, Idx = idx })
    .Where(p => !p.IsPresent)
    .Select(p => p.Idx);

string message = string.Format("Missing ids from File 1 are {0}", string.Join("," missing));
ResetBuilder.Apppend(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code which will save your second loop. In the first loop itself you will get the missing entries.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   idCheck[i] = false;
   for (int j = 0; j < FileIdArray.Length; j++) //FileIdArray is the list of all my Ids.
   {
        if (i == Convert.ToInt32(FileIdArray[j]))
        {
          idCheck[i] = true;          
          break;
        }       
   }
   if(j>=100)
    ResultBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Missing Id's from File 1 are {0}", i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your code :

```
ResultBuilder.AppendLine(String.Format("Missing Id's from File 1 are:" )

for (int i = 0; i < idCheck.Length; i++)
 {
   idCheck[0] = true;

   if (idCheck[i] == false)
    {
      ResultBuilder.Append(String.Format("{0}", i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before. This give a similar redundant o/p. Thanks for taking time to answer

Answer (score -1):

Just use the following line inside your for loop:-

```
    ResetBuilder.Append(String.Format("Missing Id's from File 1 are {0}", i)) ;
```

Comment: i already have the same thing in my code. Thanks for taking time to answer my question.